# Split a DataFrame row into multiple rows based on integer value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there way we can split a row into multiple rows based on an integer cap value? I have a dataframe as below

```
sys_df = pd.DataFrame([{'dateTime': '2020-11-12 17:45:00', 'timeTakenInSeconds': 650, 'id':'xyz'}])
```

| Index | dateTime | timeTakenInSeconds | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-11-12 17:45:00 | 650 | xyz |

I am trying to split the above row into 3 rows of previous 5 minute intervals like below.

| Index | dateTime | timeTakenInSeconds | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-11-12 17:45:00 | 300 | xyz |
| 1 | 2020-11-12 17:40:00 | 300 | xyz |
| 2 | 2020-11-12 17:35:00 | 50 | xyz |

Do we have any pandas builin utils to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own method.
A lead can be:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
origin_data = {'dateTime': '2020-11-12 17:45:00', 'timeTakenInSeconds': 650, 'id':'xyz'}

def splitter(origin_data, interval=0):
    data=[]
    to_sec = interval*60
    current_time = datetime.fromisoformat(origin_data['dateTime'])
    for item in range((origin_data['timeTakenInSeconds']//to_sec)):
        data.append({'dateTime': str(current_time),
                     'timeTakenInSeconds': to_sec, 'id':'xyz'})
        current_time -= timedelta(seconds=to_sec)
    reminder = origin_data['timeTakenInSeconds'] - (origin_data['timeTakenInSeconds']//to_sec)*to_sec
    if reminder:
        data.append({'dateTime': str(current_time),
                     'timeTakenInSeconds': reminder, 'id': 'xyz'})
    return data


print(pd.DataFrame(splitter(origin_data, interval=5)))
```

Outputs:

```
              dateTime  timeTakenInSeconds   id
0  2020-11-12 17:45:00                 300  xyz
1  2020-11-12 17:40:00                 300  xyz
2  2020-11-12 17:35:00                  50  xyz
```

**Note:**

You can also use:

```
pd.date_range(end=datetime.fromisoformat(origin_data['dateTime']), periods=3, freq='5min')
```

To split the date as you wish.